# Best Symfony 2 (2.1+) forum bundle

Tags: bundle, forum, symfony-2.1

I'm looking for Symfony2 forum bundle, which is:

1. working
2. not dead
3. supports sf 2.1

Anyone knows of such a thing?

Answer (score 4):

check this one out:

http://packagist.org/packages/herzult/forum-bundle

It has been updated recently and it is symfony 2.1 ready. You can install it through composer.

Also check http://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle that allows you to threading capabilities to your symfony application.

You can always check http://packagist.org for symfony 2.1 ready bundles ;)

If you have any problem instaling these feel free to ask.

Comment: A little update to this, Herzult forum is broken on 2.1 - https://github.com/Herzult/HerzultForumBundle/pull/51